# Script creating a new div with header and a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a script that will create a new div with header and a paragraph which will be taken from the form. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
    .h{
        width: 500px;
    }

    .p{
        width: 500px;
        height: 250px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>
<body>
        H:<br>
        <input type="text" class="h"><br><br>
        P:<br>
        <textarea class="p"></textarea><br><br>
        <button onclick="add();">Send</button>
</body>
<script>
    function add(){
        var a = document.getElementsByClassName("h");
        var b = document.getElementsByClassName("p")

        var div = document.createElement("DIV");
        var naglowek = document.createTextNode(a);
        var tresc = document.createTextNode(b);
        
        div.appendChild(naglowek);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing an array-type object to the function `createTextNode`, what you need to do is assign the value of those fields.

*I recommend you to use ids.*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<style>
    .h{
        width: 300px;
    }

    .p{
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
</style>
<body>
        H:<br>
        <input type="text" id="h" class="h"><br><br>
        P:<br>
        <textarea id="p" class="p"></textarea><br><br>
        <button onclick="add();">Send</button>
</body>
<script>
    function add(){
        var a = document.getElementById("h").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("p").value;

        var div = document.createElement("DIV");
        var naglowek = document.createTextNode(a);
        var tresc = document.createTextNode(b);
        
        div.appendChild(naglowek);
        div.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
        div.appendChild(tresc);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
</script>
</html>
```